# Combining predicate logic with Big O Notation

Tags: algorithm, logic, complexity-theory, predicate

True or false? ∀f[ f = Ω(n^2) ∧ f = O(n^3)  ⇒  f = Θ(n^2) ∨ f = Θ(n^3)]

Comment: This site is for practical programming questions. We are  not here to do your CS theory homework.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, tip for your future [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try asking at http://cs.stackexchange.com/ maybe.

Answer (score 0):

No, the statement means that the best case is Theta(n^2) and the worst case is Theta(n^3). If that statement is true, it would mean that the average case could never be different than the best or worst case, which isn't true.

See, for example, a BST, where the best case is Omega(1), average case is O(log n), and worst case is O(n). (Note that some people will disagree with me and list O(log n) as the best case, but I disagree with this).

In this case, the average case doesn't have to be either Theta(n^2) or Theta(n^3) because it could be Theta(n^2 log n), which is greater than Theta(n^2) and less than Theta(n^3). I can't think of an algorithm that actually *is* that offhand but you could at least imagine an algorithm (however contrived) that actually is.